# Objective-C declaring a multidimensional array

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array

Still learning and am trying to create a simple multidimensional array with 4 records and 4 values in each record - a string; 2x floats and an int.  The reference documentation on Objective-C seems to be mute on this, unless I have been struck blind or am using the wrong terminology.

Any ideas?
Regards,
Bruckner

Comment: Why use a multidimensional array instead of creating a class for the string, floats and int and add them to the array?

Answer (score 0):

Objective C does not contain a concept of contiguous multidimensional arrays (like in C). You can implement using array of arrays, as suggested by @GrzegorzKrukowski, but you risk mixing up indexes and order.

Here are two better solutions:

- Use a `NSDictionary` object with `NSIndexPath` objects as keys to note your index path, such as `[1, 2]`;
- Even better, create a class for your string, two floats and int, and use a regular array to store objects of this type.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
[NSMutableArray array],
[NSMutableArray array],
[NSMutableArray array],
[NSMutableArray array], nil];
```

To add int, float into any array use: NSNumber numberWithInt: or numberWithFloat:

```
[[arr objectAtIndex:0] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]];
```

To get value back

```
[[[arr objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
```

Using literals should shorten code here, but I'm using full code to clarify.

Comment: Note that this is **not** a multidimensional array. This is a jagged array, and each array can contain a different number of objects.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using below code,

```
    NSMutableArray *arrFinal=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [arr addObject:@"String"];
    [arr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",floatNumber1]];
    [arr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",floatNumber1]];
    [arr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",intnumber1]];

    [arrFinal addObject:arr];//add that array to final array.

    arr=nil;

    //If you want to access it then
    NSMutableArray *arrRecord1=[arrFinal objectAtIndex:0];
```

Instead of that my suggestion is create a objective c class whose parent is `NSObject` just to define entity as below

```
//in .h class
@interface UOMList : NSObject
{
    int idUnits;
    NSString *cUnitCode;   
}

@property (nonatomic)int idUnits;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *cUnitCode;

-(id)init;
-(void)dealloc;

@end

//in .m class
@implementation UOMList
@synthesize idUnits;
@synthesize cUnitCode;


-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.cUnitCode=@"";
        idUnits=0;
    }
    return self;
}



//releaseContent method to release the content
-(void)releaseContent:(id)sender
{
    [sender release];
    sender=nil;
}


//dealloc method to release the content
-(void)dealloc
{
    [self releaseContent:cUnitCode];
    [super dealloc];

}
```

Now whenever you required to fill data in record allocate object for it and  save it in the array as below

```
UOMList *obj1=[[UOMList alloc]init];
obj1.cUnitCode=@"String";
obj1.idUnits=intval;
[arrFinal addObject:obj1];
```

Then you can access it as below

```
UOMList *obj1=[arrFinal objectAtIndex:0];
```

Second method so simple. I hope this will help you.